# A Pythagorian inequality characterization of inner-product spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, inequalities

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a real normed space. For any points $A$ and $B$ in $X$, let $AB:=\|A-B\|$. Suppose that for any points $A$ and $B$ in $X$ and any straight line   $\ell\subseteq X$ such that $B\in\ell$ we have 
$$AB^2\ge AA_\ell^2+BA_\ell^2 
$$
for some point $A_\ell$ on $\ell$ that is at the smallest distance to $A$ among all points on $\ell$ (it is easy to see that such a point $A_\ell$ always exists). 
Does it then necessarily follow that the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is induced by an inner product?

Perhaps easier to answer is the version of this question with 
**"for some point $A_\ell$ on $\ell$ that is at the smallest distance to $A$"** 
replaced by
**"for all points $A_\ell$ on $\ell$ that are at the smallest distance to $A$"**.

(I was not sure if this question is appropriate for MO, but then saw [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141522/a-property-that-forces-the-norm-to-be-induced-by-an-inner-product), which seems to be of the same flavor.)

Comment: When you say that $A_\ell$ is "**the** closest to $A$ among all points on $\ell$" do you just mean "a point on $\ell$ whose distance to $A$ is minimal" or "a unique point whose distance to $A$ is minimal"?

Comment: (My point being that closest points will exist by compactness but I don't see why they should be unique)

Comment: Final comment for now: it seems that it would suffice (for a positive or negative answer) to restrict to the case $\dim(X)=2$, unless I have made a silly error

Comment: @YemonChoi : Thank you for your comments. (i) I have replaced "the closest" by "at the smallest distance". (ii) I was cognizant of the nonuniqueness issue, which is why I offered two versions of the question. (iii) I too guess that the problem is probably mostly two dimensional, with perhaps some extra efforts needed to harmonize between the different two-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Regarding (iii), here was my line of thought: if there is a 2-dimensional counterexample we are done. Conversely, suppose we know that in dimension 2 this property characterizes the Euclidean norm. Then for an arbitrary X satisfying your condition, I take two vectors x and y generating a 2-dim subspace V. Applying your condition to points and lines in V, I deduce that the subspace norm on V is Euclidean. But since this holds for all 2-dim subspaces of X, X is Euclidean/Hilbertian (parallelogram identity)

Comment: @YemonChoi, I guess "[by compactness](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348730/a-pythagorian-inequality-characterization-of-inner-product-spaces#comment873469_348730)" means something like "the set of all points within distance $r$ of $A$ on $\ell$, where $r$ is big enough that the set is non-empty, is compact".  Is that obvious, for an abstract real normed space (not assumed compact or finite dimensional)?  Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @LSpice Well just take a sequence of points on $\ell$ that get closer and closer to attaining the infimum of "distance from $A$". This sequence is contained in some bounded ball around $A$ so apply Bolzano-Weierstrass to extract a convergent subsequence

Comment: [@YemonChoi](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348730/a-pythagorian-inequality-characterization-of-inner-product-spaces#comment873490_348730), I know Bolzano–Weierstrass only for Euclidean space.  Does it hold in an abstract real normed space?  (Or perhaps, since we're on a line, it's enough to think in terms of a coördinate on the line, and so reduce to BW on $\mathbb R$?)

Comment: (I think actually [BW](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348730/a-pythagorian-inequality-characterization-of-inner-product-spaces#comment873491_348730) doesn't hold even in an arbitrary inner-product space—e.g., an appropriate scaling of an orthonormal basis in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space; but, aha, the whole test takes place in the space spanned by $A$, $B$, and the line, and so we may as well assume we're in a finite-dimensional space, in which case the norm is equivalent to a Euclidean one, hence the notions of boundedness agree and BW applies.  So I am no longer concerned!)